# PHP: checking for $_GET variables with if statements

Tags: php

This code gets me where I need to be, but my word it is ugly.

I am checking for the existence of two $_GET variables with if() statements. I am setting the variables to empty strings first so I do not get an error when I echo them back.

```
$getvar1 ='';
$getvar2 ='';
$np ='';

if(isset($_GET['getvar1'])) $page_id = $_GET['getvar2'];
if(isset($_GET['getvar2'])) $route = $_GET['getvar2']; 

if(($getvar1 == '' && $getvar1 == '') || $getvar1 == '4')  $np = 'np'; 

    echo "$getvar1 $getvar2 $np";
```

Is there a better way to declare the variables than setting them to empty strings?

Is there a better way to check and set the $_GET variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a small app something like that would probably be better:

```
$getvar = isset($_GET['getvar']) ? $_GET['getvar'] : 'somedefault';
```

If you want to test more stuff:

```
$getvar = isset($_GET['getvar']) && $JUST_PUT_IT_HERE ? $_GET['getvar'] : 'somedefault';
```

Comment: Don't forget to sanitize/filter when you're pulling in data like $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, etc or you could have vulnerabilities later on 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Answer (score 3):

How about writing a function like this:

```
function getOrDefault($index, $default)
{
    return (!isset($_GET[$index]) || empty($_GET[$index]) ? $default : $_GET[$index]);
}

$getVar1 = getOrDefault('getvar1', '');
$getVar2 = getOrDefault('getvar2', '');
```

This function should be as general as possible and be located somewhere in a `function-library`. I don't know about the rest of your project. But for example if you do have some kind of `request` object (containing all information about the current (http)request), you could write specialized versions:

```
class Request()
{
    public function getPost($param, $default = '')
    {
        if(!isset($_POST[$param]) || empty($_POST[$param])
        {
            return $default;
        }
        return $_POST[$param];
    }

    // If param is set both in $_GET and $_POST, $_GET is return.
    public function getParam($param, $default = '')
    {
        if(!isset($_GET[$param]) || empty($_GET[$param))
        {
            return $this->getPost($param, $default);
        }
        return $_GET[$param];
    }
}

$getVar1 = $request->getParam('getVar1', '');
$getVar2 = $request->getParam('getVar2', '');
```

Comment: You could use $_REQUEST as well...

Answer (score 2):

**Array Merge**

If you're just setting defaults, you could use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$defaults = array(
    'getvar1' => 'default setting', //a default value
    'getvar2' => false //now you can just test
);

$params = array_merge($defaults, $_GET); //any missing elements get the default value

echo $params['getvar1']; //will output 'default setting' if $_GET['getvar1'] was not set

if($params['getvar2']){
     //do something if $_GET['getvar2'] was set to a non-false value
}
```

It should be noted that this only works with things like `$_GET` - that are already arrays. The [ternary](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) [method](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/php-checking-for-get-variables-with-if-statements/3832#3832), a [`getOrDefault()`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/php-checking-for-get-variables-with-if-statements/3829#3829) function, or some [enigmatic logic operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732403/can-someone-explain-this-line-of-code-please-logic-assignment-operators/1732428#1732428) code is better suited when setting defaults not already in an array.

**Logic Operators**

Here's an example of using logic operators (similar to using ternary operator) from the default Zend MVC `index.php`:

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

Using the question's example, it would look something like this:

```
isset($_GET['getvar1']) || $_GET['getvar1'] = 'default value';
```